# Unable to get Libre Office to load on redhat 6. Get stuck at the splash screen

Tags: linux, redhat, libreoffice-calc

This recently starting happening. I had been happily using libre office previously. I have tried rebooting and re-installing libre office with no effect. Using version 5.3.3.2-2.x86_64 of libre office. Using Redhat 6 version 2.6.32-642.15.1.el6.x86_64.
Process status shows

```
 jgaer@ljgaer1_/tmp/RPMS: ps -eafl | grep libre
 0 S jgaer     5860     1  0  80   0 - 75116 futex_ 04:33 ?          00:00:00 /opt/libreoffice5.3/program/oosplash --calc
 0 S jgaer     5878  5860  0  80   0 - 202475 futex_ 04:33 ?       00:00:00 /opt/libreoffice5.3/program/soffice.bin --calc --splash-pipe=5
 0 S jgaer     6078  5056  0  80   0 - 25830 pipe_w 04:46 pts/0    00:00:00 grep libre
```

Comment: Try use `strace`, something like `strace -f -e open -o /tmp/log command`, to find out what config files inside $HOME used by libreoffice, and move config file/directory to some other place.

Comment: thanks that led me to it

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

removing the directory $HOME/.config/libreoffice corrected the problem.